# react navigation reset and redirect to home screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I want to reset navigation when user logged in after then we will redirect to home page i have try this

```
    const Root = StackNavigator({
                 Unauthorized: { screen: UnAuthorized },
                 Authorized: { screen: Authorized },
               }, {
                    headerMode: 'screen',
                    navigationOptions: {
                    header: null
                 }
         });

       const Authorized = DrawerNavigator({
                        Home: { screen: Home }        
              });

       const UnAuthorized = StackNavigator({
                 Splash: { screen: Splash },
                 Login: { screen: Login },
              });


 await axios.post(url+'rest_users/login',user)
    .then(function (response) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGGED_IN,
        payload: response.data
      });
      const resetNavigator = NavigationActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        key: null,
        actions: [
          NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: 'Authorized',
            action: [
              NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Home'})]
          })
        ],
      });
      dispatch(resetNavigator);
```

Navigation showing reset in logs but i have not seen any screen moving changes. Please help me where i am going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems, you are using dispatch method of Redux, not React-Navigation in order to dispatch your resetAction.

What you should do is pass navigation prop from your component to the place where you need to dispatch the resetAction and then call `navigation.dispatch(resetAction)`

Comment: @PrashantJangid You are welcome. Glad you solved it! ;)